# Interesting basic DP problem (Theif loot houses)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

A thief wants to loot houses. He knows the amount of money in each house. He cannot loot three consecutive houses. Find the maximum amount of money he can loot.

example -

6
[5 5 10 100 10 5]

5+10+100+5=120.

After this can we generalize for he cannot loot k consecutive houses.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your effort?

Comment: In above example, I think it should have been  `[(5) 5 (10) (100) 10 (5)]` which would have given 120

Comment: yeah you are right.

Comment: @ArunGowda I could solve no two consecutive loot. Having a lot of confusion in approaching this beautiful problem. :(

Comment: @JansthcirlU yeah that's also a possible way. Question says just to tell the maximum amount of loot possible. It will be another nice problem to determine the no ways leading to maximum amount of loot.

Comment: Thieves obey rules? ;)

Comment: definitely otherwise a[i]>0 then ans is for every i, sum of all a[i]'s

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If they don't, the CCTV will catch the thief. Atleast CCTV follow the rules. STRICTLY :D

Comment: ha ha ha definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to remember DP is trying to mimic an exhaustive search. In your example, the thief needs to chose for each house if he should loot it or not. He has an extra restriction of the amount of consecutive houses he had "visited" (this can be taken care of as a base clause, I find it simpler to follow).

This gives us the following recursive formula:

```
Base clause 1 for forbidden path:
T(i, 0) = -INFINITY   
Base clause 2 before looting any house:
T(0, c) = 0
Recursive formula:
T(i, c) = max { T(i-1, c-1) + loot[i] , T(i-1, k) }
                       ^                    ^
               loot i'th hourse       Skip i'th house
```

When done, the solution lies with `T(n,c)` for some `1 <= c <= k`

Comment: T(i, c) = max { T(i-1, c-1) + loot[i] , T(i-1, k) } .  I think it should be this.